# Анимация затухания

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста
написал вот такой вот скрипт, который меняет один текст на другой
как сделать небольшую анимацию в виду затухания?

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 function substitute() {
 $('#water').html('Вода');
 $('#water-last').html('для жизни');
 setTimeout(function(){
 $('#water').html('Water')
 $('#water-last').html('for life')},3000);
 };
 $(function() {
 setInterval(substitute,6000);
 });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Посмотрите на методы fadeIn() и .fadeOut()

Comment: делал по инструкции. не шарю совсем в синтаксе JQuery, больше по ваниле. Куда его подставить? :(

Comment: @СергейЛетов http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ вот мануал по fadein\out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function substitute() {
 $('#water').text('Вода');
 $('#water-last').text('для жизни');
 $('#text').fadeIn(2000, function(){
  $('#text').fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $('#water').text('Water');
    $('#water-last').text('for life');
    $('#text').fadeIn(2000, function(){
      $('#text').fadeOut(2000);
     })  
   });
  })};
 (function() {
 setInterval(substitute,8000);
 })();
```

```css
#text{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='text'>
<div id="water"></div>
<div id="water-last"></div>
</div>
```